# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la dirección IP del cliente cuando en el servidor existe un balanceador de carga en Java, utilizando protocolo SOAP?

Tags: java

Requiero obtener la Ip y el Host de los usuarios cuando envían una petición a mi endpoint wsdl, utilicé esta implementación., solo que al realizar pruebas me obtiene la Ip y el Host del balanceador y no la Ip-Host original del usuario que manda una petición al principio.

Muestro código el cual implemento :

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext context;

@WebMethod(operationName = "Clientes")
@WebResult(name = "xml")
public String ClienteWS(@WebParam(name = "xml") String requestClientesWS) {     
    String cadena = requestClientesWS.replaceAll("##", "&ntilde;");

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getMessageContext()
            .get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    String ipPeticion=request.getRemoteAddr();
    String hostPeticion = request.getRemoteHost();
            
return client.estatusClientesWS(cadena.replaceAll("&", "&amp;"), ipPeticion, hostPeticion);
}
```

Comment: X-Forwarded-for es la cabecera que necesitas

Comment: Al implementarlo de la siguiente manera:

String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
 log.info("dddd "+ipAddress );

Me muestra como null

Comment: Tienes que revisar que el balanceador y todos en el despliegue deben implementar el uso de la cabecera.

Answer (score -2):

Buen día,

Como podría obtener el hostname del cliente en java? Para obtener la ip usando balanceador de carga utilizo:

```
String ipClient= req.getHeader("Client-IP");
```

Para obtener el hostmane útilizo la clase...

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ipClient); 
String host = address.getHostName;
```

Pero en un balanceador de carga en vez de obtener el hostname me devuelve la ip del cliente de la petición petición mandó y ya no se como o si lo implemento mal

Comment: Está no es una respuesta, es otra pregunta